# jQuery replace a class attribute

Tags: jquery, html, attr

How can I change a class value to be a different value:

Here is the html:

```
<div class="example_infobox">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="info-box">
      <span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span>
      <div class="info-box-content">
        <span class="info-box-text">Messages</span>
        <span class="info-box-number">1,410</span>
      </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
    </div><!-- /.info-box -->
  </div><!-- /.col -->
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$('.example_infobox .info-box-icon.bg-aqua').attr('class', 'info-box-icon ' + 'bg-green');
```

The above jQuery code changes:

```
<span class="info-box-icon bg-aqua">
```

to:

```
<span class="info-box-icon bg-green">
```

The above code works, but is it possible to write jQuery code to change the class by just replacing the `bg-aqua` with `bg-green` without having to specify the whole class (as I have done in my jQuery code)? By this I mean, is it possible to replace a part of the class with a new value, similar to string.replace in C#?

Thanks

Comment: Use addClass() or removeClass().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`$.fn.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

*Use*

```
$('.example_infobox .info-box-icon.bg-aqua').toggleClass('bg-aqua bg-green');
```

*OR*, Combination of [`$.fn.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and  [`$.fn.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$('.example_infobox .info-box-icon.bg-aqua').removeClass('bg-aqua').addClass('bg-green');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first check which class exist in it by '.hasClass()'. Then you can apply adding and removing classes like this:

```
if($('.example_infobox .info-box-icon.bg-aqua').hasClass('bg-green'))
{
    $('.example_infobox-icon').removeClass('bg-green').addClass('bg-aqua');
}
else
{
    $('.example_infobox-icon').removeClass('bg-aqua').addClass('bg-green');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.example_infobox-icon').removeClass('bg-aqua').addClass('bg-green')
```